# Writing on a register in parallel in CUDA C++

Tags: cuda

Given a 64-bit variable in a register in a kernel, let's say std::uint64_t var, I want to do some calculations and set each bit of this variable using 64 different threads separately but in parallel. Is it possible to write on a shared variable in parallel?

```
__shared__ std::uint64_t var = 0
in each thread (tid = 0 to 63):
   do some calculations
   if we should set the bit with index = tid then:
      var |= ((std::uint64_t) 1 << tid)
```

I also realized that using atomicOr does not benefit us as it only works on integers.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot operate on bits of `var` truly in parallel because no hardware can do that. The best is maybe to use an `atomicOr`. Some architecture can to a clever reduction for `atomicAdd` so it might be the case for `atomicOr` (to be checked). Still, threads of different warps will not work on `var` in parallel (at least not yet AFAIK) so the operation will be serialized. Note that the condition will cause a divergeance so it is likely better to use a branchless approach.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your time. As I mentioned in my question, I tried to use atomicOr, however, unfortunately, I realized that it works only on integers and not 64-bit variables.

Comment: There is a 64-bit version of `atomicOr`, assuming you have a cc3.5 or newer/higher device. And I don't see why you couldn't break this into 2 32-bit shared variables, and each thread decides whether it will update the first or second.  Your usage of the term "in a register" is also not appropriate here.

Comment: I do not think this is much a problem. You can do 64-bit atomic operation on >=3.5 CUDA devices (not a bit restriction). If this is a problem, you can split the 64-bit variable into 2 32-bit ones (while taking care about the endianess). Besides, there is the [`__ballot_sync` and `__activemask`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) function that seems to help a lot to do that efficiently. Note that they operate on warps so you need to merge the result (typically using a union). AFAIK Nvidia GPUs use little-endian (though it is better to check)

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks, I am using Colab Pro, and I don't know why it does not accept 64-bit atomicOr and returns error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicOr" matches the argument list argument types are: (UINT, UINT), which UINT is std::uint64_t in my code.

Comment: @MojtabaValizadeh Maybe you build the code with a compatibility to an old version of CUDA or maybe the devices are (very?) old. You can check the CUDA compute capability with `nvidia-smi`. As for the build, AFAIR you can tweak this with options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a 64-bit shared `atomicOr()`:

```
$ cat t2082.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

__global__ void k(){

  __shared__ unsigned long long var;
  if (!threadIdx.x) var = 0;
  __syncthreads();
  atomicOr(&var, 1<<threadIdx.x);
  __syncthreads();
  if (!threadIdx.x) printf("0x%lx\n", var);
}

int main(){
  k<<<1,64>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2082 t2082.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2082
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0xffffffffffffffff
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

The 64-bit shared `atomicOr` is supported on devices of cc3.5 or greater, which is the same device footprint supported by CUDA 11.

If you were, for example, on CUDA 10.x and using a cc3.0 device, you could do this with two 32-bit variables:

```
$ cat t2082.cu
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

__global__ void k(){

  __shared__ unsigned var[2];
  if (!threadIdx.x) {var[0] = 0; var[1] = 0;}
  __syncthreads();
  if (threadIdx.x < 32)
    atomicOr(&(var[0]), 1<<threadIdx.x);
  else
    atomicOr(&(var[1]), 1<<(threadIdx.x-32));
  __syncthreads();
  unsigned long long var64 = (((unsigned long long)var[1])<<32) +  var[0];
  if (!threadIdx.x) printf("0x%lx\n", var64);
}

int main(){
  k<<<1,64>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2082 t2082.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2082
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
0xffffffffffffffff
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am using Colab Pro, and I don't know why it does not accept 64-bit atomicOr and returns error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicOr" matches the argument list argument types are: (UINT, UINT), which UINT is std::uint64_t in my code. I'll try using two 32-bit variables then.

Comment: BTW, AFAIK, atomicOr makes everything sequential. So, apparently, there is no way to set each bit of a variable in parallel. Yes?

Comment: That is correct.  Atomics serialize.  You cannot set bits of a byte "in parallel" (i.e. safely, from different threads, without serialization) in CUDA.  If you are using an older version of CUDA in your machine, you may need to add a `-arch=sm_XX` switch to your compilation, to get access to the 64-bit version. The XX will depend on what GPU is in your instance.